# Mediawiki Sitemap With short URLs

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler, mediawiki, sitemap, robots.txt

I have installed the mediawiki on my site like this: mysite.com/index.php/Main_page

I have used the Short URL method to change the url to mysite.com/Main_Page

What exactly I have to put on my robots.txt file?

I don't know how to follow this guide:

> https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Robots.txt#With_short_URLs`

because the main install was on the root.

Comment: What is it that you want to prevent robots from seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The linked tutorial is still valid, as long as you did not reconfigure your script URL (the one you see when editing pages).

Whether your robots.txt will work is another question; it will now reside in the same URL space as your wiki pages...